# Promises chaining: Adding an error handler when creating a Promise vs adding to a variable with a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
function getPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 2000, new Error('fail'));
    });
}

const promise1 = getPromise();
promise1.catch(() => {
    // NOP
});

promise1
    .then(() => console.log('then promise1'))
    .catch(() => console.error('catch promise1'));

const promise2 = getPromise().catch(() => {
    // NOP
});

promise2
    .then(() => console.log('then promise2'))
    .catch(() => console.error('catch promise2'));
```

#### Output

```
catch promise1
then promise2
```

#### Explanations

Here `promise2` will be processed differently then `promise1`. While `promise1` will be rejected with 'fail' error, `promise2` will be resolved with `undefined`.

#### My environment

Ubuntu 14.04, Node.js 10.1.0

#### Question

I think this behavior is not obvious. Why does the code work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you chain the second then not to the rejecting promise, but to the promise returned by `catch`, which will resolve to whatever you return from the `catch` handler.

```
 Promise(promise1)
  -❎-> catch
  -✔-> then -❎- > catch
  -❎-----------------^

Promise
  -❎-> catch(promise2)
           -✔-> then -❎-> catch
           -❎-----------------^
  -✔------------^
```

In the first case, the promise rejects, so it will enter the `catch` directly assigned to it, and it will skip the `then`, going directly to the chained `catch`. In the second case, the promise rejects and the `catch` will be executed, but then it seems to handle the error, so the chained `then` will be called. If you don't want that, the `catch` has to re`throw` the error, then the `then` will be skipped and it also enters the chained `catch`.

Answer (score 2):

`Catch` returns a new promise:

```js
let orig = Promise.reject("fail")
let p = orig.catch(console.log)

console.log("is p the same as orig? ", p === orig)

p.then(() => console.log('p is a promise?', p instanceof Promise))
```

So when you call

```
 const promise2 = getPromise().catch(() => { //..})
```

and assign the value to a `promise2` that is a brand new promise returned from `catch`. In the first case you use the oringal `promise1` in both statements.

To make the first statement work like the second, you would need to do something like:

```js
function getPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 2000, new Error('fail'));
    });
}

let promise1 = getPromise();

// reassign the value of promise1
promise1 = promise1.catch(() => {
    // NOP
});

promise1
    .then(() => console.log('then promise1'))
    .catch(() => console.error('catch promise1'));
```

Which is also the equivalent of just doing:

```
promise1
  .catch(() => {/* noop */ })
  .then(() => console.log('then promise1'))
  .catch(() => console.error('catch promise1'));
```

Also, if you want to make sure the error is passed down the chain, you can always return a rejected promise from `catch`:

```
let promise1 = getPromise().catch((e) => {
    return Promise.reject(e)
});
```